# How to suppress a specific unused-but-set-variable warning?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, armclang

I've got some old code I'm trying to compile on a new(er) compiler (armclang 6.18), and I'm currently working through resolving a lot of new warnings. One I can't seem to get past is a variable that's being set but is unused afterward.

```
void IMT_hw_startup(void) {
    uint32_t encoder_value_0;
//[...]
    encoder_value_0 = encoder_values[0];
}
```

In this case the read access to `encoder_values` has hardware side effects and must remain in place.

The result of this code is `warning: variable 'encoder_value_0' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]`, and my primary question is how I can suppress the warning for this specific variable. I do want to keep this warning active globally.

In searching about this, there seems to be a lot of confusion and conflation between this warning and `unused-variable`, and at any rate there's an attribute that will suppress the latter but I can't find one for `unused-but-set-variable`.

Also a curiosity -- less important than the primary question above: There appears to be an inconsistency in what 'used' actually means. According to the above warning, the variable is **not used**; this seems unambiguous.

But if I add the unused attribute:

```
uint32_t encoder_value_0 __attribute((unused));
```

Then I get the warning `warning: 'encoder_value_0' was marked unused but was used [-Wused-but-marked-unused]` where the variable is assigned a value (final statement in the function). I can see no alternative interpretation -- this is a direct contradiction of the above warning. Either assignment is "use", or it's not.

At any rate, how do I suppress the warning for this case individually, so I can leave the warning active elsewhere?

EDIT: As suggested, changing the method of reading from the encoder_values pointer does work around the problem by eliminating the need for the variable:

```
if (encoder_values[0]) {}
```

I'm leaving this question up in case there's a more direct answer to it.

Comment: Does `volatile` work?

Comment: How can assigning to a local variable have HW side effects? Shouldn't it be a pointer to a specific address?

Comment: Well, if `encoder_value_0` really isn't used anywhere, why not remove it?

Comment: It's not the assignment, it's the read from `encoder_values` that has side effects (it is a pointer to a specific hardware address). Using `volatile` has no effect on the warning.

Comment: can you not just have a line like `if (encoder_values[0]) { /* do nothing, just need to read... */ }`

Comment: How does the compiler know there are side effects when reading `encoder_values[0]`? If compiler assumes no side effects (pretty reasonable if you ask me) it may very well skip the whole statement (and the runtime side-effects), seeing it says `encoder_value_0` is not used. Anyway ... add `if (encoder_value_0) /*void*/;` somewhere in an attempt to shut the compiler up :)

Comment: what happens if you put `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-but-set-variable"` right before that line? see https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100067/0612/Compiler-specific-Pragmas/-pragma-clang-diagnostic?lang=en

Comment: @dave Your first suggestion does work to eliminate the warning, though there's some more work to do before I'm able to test it.  I'm going to leave this question up though because I would like to see if there's an answer, even if I work around it in this case. Your second suggestion -- does that only affect the following line, or the entire function (as seems to be indicated in the docs)?

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer, not an edit to the question. If no better answers are given, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @Barmar Agreed -- I will post as an answer if I don't get any that seem better or more specific to the question.

Comment: You can have multiple answers. Yours can be one of them.

Comment: @dave Experimenting a bit, I've found that the #pragma you suggest applies not only to the function, but to the entire file. Unfortunately this is not quite the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @ChrisRobison you need to do `#pragma clang diagnostic push` before and `#pragma clang diagnostic pop` after

Answer (score 4):

If reading from `encoder_values[0]` has hardware side effects, then presumably it is declared with `volatile`, and the way to effect those side effects in C is simply to evaluate `encoder_values[0]`, with no assignment necessary:

```
encoder_values[0];
```

If you do assign to `encoder_value_0` for some reason and want to suppress the compiler warning about its value not being used, then simply “use” the value in a statement that tells the compiler you are deliberately discarding it:

```
(void) encoder_value_0;
```

Note that if `encoder_values[0]` is not declared with `volatile`, then writing `encoder_values_0 = encoder_values[0];` will not ensure it is read. With no `volatile` type involved and `encoder_value_0` not used for any observable behavior, the compiler is free to optimize away the assignment. (This is so even if `(void) encoder_value_0;` is also added, as that has no observable behavior in C semantics.)

Answer (score 2):

An additional variable is not needed for the read only. The easiest way is:

```
encoder_values[0];
```

*removed `(void)` - as per @EricPostpischil's suggestion

Assuming that `encoder_values` are `volatile`. (If it is not the read will be optimized out anyway - so it has to be. It is also hardware register )

```
void IMT_hw_startup(void) {
    encoder_values[0];
}
```

Comment: The `(void)` cast here is problematic similarly to the way casts on `malloc` are—it has no benefit and can conceal an error. If `encoder_values[0]` is `volatile` qualified, the compiler will not warn when `encoder_values[0];` is used alone, so there is no need to use `(void)` to suppress the warning. However, if it is accidentally not `volatile` qualified, using `(void)` will suppress the warning the compiler would give (if enabled) if `encoder_values[0];` were used alone.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it is rather unlikely hardware register to be declared as not volatile

Comment: The benefit of using `(void)` is zero. The benefit is not using `(void)` is, according to you, an unlikely chance of avoiding an error, and hence a small benefit. A small benefit exceeds a zero benefit. Therefore, `(void)` should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `push` and `pop` to save and revert the diagnostic state, so you should be able to do:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-but-set-variable"
encoder_value_0 = encoder_values[0];
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```